# Dynamic content in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

i want to use a single popup that shows up when different list elements are clicked and I want the list elements to give the popup its information. I gave it a shot but i can't seem to fetch the text (from the li element) dynamically to the popup

A list item:

```
    <ul id="wizard-card-list">
        <li class="wizard-card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#emailpopup">
            <a href="#" class="cd-popup-trigger">
                <img class="wizard-card-avatar" src="img/avatars/chrisandashley.png">
                <h5 class="wizard-name">Chris & Ashley</h5>
                <span>U.S.A. West Coast</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The PopUp:

```
 <div id="email-popup" class="modal cd-popup" role="alert">
        <div class="cd-popup-container">
            <div id="popup-wizard-name"
            <p>Chris & Ashley</p>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
        </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
      </div> <!-- cd-popup -->
```

The javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

//open popup
$('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
    var element = $(event.relatedTarget); // the li that triggered the modal to show
    var dynamic_text = element.find('.wizard-name').text(); // Extract the value of the .text div inside that li

    event.preventDefault();
    $('#email-popup').addClass('is-visible');

    $("#popup-wizard-name").html('the users post says: ' + dynamic_text );

});
```

Comment: Did you try using `$(this)` instead of `$(event.relatedTarget)`?

Comment: Wow! how could i've overlooked this?! Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$(event.relatedTarget)` :

```
var element = $(this); // the li that triggered the modal to show
var dynamic_text = element.find('.wizard-name').text(); // Extract the value of the .text div inside that li
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `relatedTarget` you can use `$(this)`. Check updated snippet below..

```js
//open popup
$('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
   // var element = $(event.relatedTarget); // the li that triggered the modal to show
    var dynamic_text = $(this).find('.wizard-name').text(); // Extract the value of the .text div inside that li

    event.preventDefault();
    $('#email-popup').addClass('is-visible');

    $("#popup-wizard-name").html('the users post says: ' + dynamic_text );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="wizard-card-list">
        <li class="wizard-card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#emailpopup">
            <a href="#" class="cd-popup-trigger">
                <img class="wizard-card-avatar" src="img/avatars/chrisandashley.png">
                <h5 class="wizard-name">Chris & Ashley</h5>
                <span>U.S.A. West Coast</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 

 <div id="email-popup" class="modal cd-popup" role="alert">
        <div class="cd-popup-container">
            <div id="popup-wizard-name">
            <p>Chris & Ashley</p>
            <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
        </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
      </div> <!-- cd-popup -->
```